# C++ Timer (Wait A Certain Period Of Time)

Tags: c++, linux, time, timer, client-server

I'm trying to write some Linux code that will send a message every 30 seconds.  What I have so far is:

```
#include <time.h>
time_t timeinit;
time_t timenow;

time(&timeinit);
while (1) {
    time(&timenow);
    if (difftime(timenow, timeinit) >= 30){
        std::cout << "Timer Test";
        time(&timeinit); //reset timeinit and recount 30 seconds
    } //end if
}
```

However, when I run it, it doesn't seem to do anything.  The way I understand it, time() give me the time now, and difftime() gives me the difference between the 2 times.  I cannot use something like sleep() because the program may receive a message at any time.

The way I am trying to get this to work is: get the initial time, then every loop get the time after that and send a message if the difference between the 2 times is 30 seconds.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?  I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Two things: 1) Log the value returned by `difftime` so you can ensure it's what you think it is. 2) Add a `<< std::flush` to the end of the output line.

Comment: Any reasons to not use crontab ?

Comment: The code is jut fine, it works for me! Hope you are waiting for 30 seconds to see the output in the terminal

Comment: A busy waiting timer might not be the very best idea to implement such. Either side, client and server.

Comment: @caduchon I've never heard of it.  I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @navta Any recommendations on what to use besides a busy timer?  I can't think of any other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

David had it right.  It worked, just wasn't displaying until I used std::flush